# TextBox Partially Editable

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it possible to make the contents of a `TextBox` or a `RichTextBox` parially editable?  For instance, I would like to have something that looks like the following:

```
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" FontFamily="Courier New" Margin="10,0">
    This text and anything before it isn't editable.

    This Text is Editable

    This text and anything after it is not editable.
</TextBox>
```

or something like this:

```
<RichTextBox AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" FontFamily="Courier New" Margin="10,0">
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>This text and anything before it is not editable.</Paragraph>
        <Paragraph>This text is editable.</Paragraph>
        <Paragraph>This text and anything after it is not editable.</Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

Ideally, I would be able to style the editable text different than the uneditable text.  Before anybody tells me I shouldn't do this, I have a valid reason for doing it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is *possible* - however, you would have to write your own code to check each attempted edit, and that will undoubtedly get very complicated in order to cover all edge cases. Have you fully considered other options, such as displaying the non-editable text in a different control, or using some markers in the text to easily be able to pull out the text they're actually supposed to edit? It would be *much* easier than what you're trying to do.

Comment: The biggest thing I need is for the text that's not editable to be displayed next and scroll with the text that is editable.  Is there a way I can do that with multiple controls?

Comment: You should be able to encapsulate the three controls into a scrollable region and resize your editable field as needed (i.e., the editable field has no scrolling, only the containing region). It's not very pretty, especially if there isn't an easy way of doing it with XAML (I've never used it, so I can't say), but I would content it's far better than trying to hack this thing into (Rich)TextBox.

Comment: That worked perfectly Michael.  Thanks for the help.  If you want to stick your comment into an answer I'll check it off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to encapsulate the three controls into a scrollable region and resize your editable field as needed (i.e., the editable field has no scrolling, only the containing region).

It's not very pretty, especially if there isn't an easy way of doing it with XAML (I've never used it, so I can't say), but I would content it's far better than trying to hack this thing into (Rich)TextBox.

Answer (score 2):

A textBox with its `Template` overrriden to hide its border and 2 textblocks of same look and feel put ahead and post the textbox in that `Template` can achieve what you seek.

[Default textbox template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645061%28VS.95%29.aspx) which you can override is here...

Comment: This is probably the best way to do what I'm trying to do, but it's a little beyond the scope of my current project.  Still, thanks for the answer.