# WPF - partially uneditable textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there a way to add a fixed piece of text (TextBlock or Label) inside WPF's TextBox? Such that; user can write text around it in the control, but can't delete or edit it?

I am looking for the reciprocal of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863930/textbox-partially-editable), that is:

```
<TextBox>
    "Chunk #1: This part of text is editable"

    "Chunk #2: This piece is not editable"

    "Chunk #3: This text is editable"
</TextBox>
```

<sub>(Note: these are the imaginary chucks there for elaboration, its all continuation of one block of text; which may be multi-line with line-breaks).</sub>

where `Chunk #2` should move accordingly, as user edits `Chunk #1` and `#3`.

Comment: Your best bet is to use an `ItemsControl` comprised of several `TextBlock`s and `TextBox`es.

Comment: Controls are designed to handle most common senarios not every (infinite) cases programmers may need. But you can still write your own using builtin ones.

Comment: Although the questions are "inverted," the answer will likely be the same - you will need to re-template the TextBox control.

Comment: @HighCore, you mean `<ItemsControl><TextBox/><TextBlock/><TextBox/></ItemsControl>` and decorate `ItemsControl` to make it look like a big `TexBox` and remove styling from `TextBox`es and TextBlock? Would the `TextBox`es get expanded automatically as the user type in?

Comment: @Annie yes, pretty much, but use DataBinding and create a proper ViewModel instead of hardcoded XAML, in order to have a dynamic number of TextBlocks/Boxes. Also, yes they would get expanded as the user types if you use an appropiate (Wrap)Panel and `Width="Auto"` or something.

Comment: @HighCore, thanks. I only need one `TextBlock` with fixed text, surrounded by editable text.

Comment: Hi don't use items control that's mainly used to bind to a collection. The best thing to do is make your control into a user control so you can reuse it. So create a new user control which could be made up of a stack panel as @helb has mentioned below and then just expose the properties you want to set for example the text of the textbox from the user control as dependency properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use three TextBox controls within a StackPanel:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBox BorderThickness="1,1,0,1"/>
        <TextBox BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" 
                 Text="Chunk 2" IsReadOnly="True"
                 IsTabStop="False" />
        <TextBox BorderThickness="0,1,1,1"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Resulting view]

**EDIT**: You should be able to jump from the first TextBox to the last using the Tab key.

Comment: Thank you. Its a good solution. Would be awesome, if we can bind arrow keys such that when forward key is press on last character of chunk 1, it enters chunk 2 region.

Comment: @Annie Set IsTabStop="False" for the middle TextBox and you can do just that with the Tab key. I will update my answer later...

Comment: Thanks. But I just realized that the text is not wrapping beyond the first row, with `Grid.Column="3"`..

Comment: @Annie The Grid and the Row/Column setup is for demonstration only. Not sure what you mean by "not wrapping beyond the first row". Also, there is only column 0, 1, and 2.    You can put the StackPanel wherever you want inside your UI.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I mean, in normal text box, the user can enter multi-line text. The text will be wrapped to next line as it get overflowed. In this case, its not wrapping. Ideally, all three controls should have a synchronous wrapping behavior from its parent (StackPanel). i.e. To make "Long text before non-editable slug `Non-editable text` text after the static slug" in same order while retaining the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I might think a masked text box is a possible outside the box solution to this.  Check out [this article](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox) on on codeplex in the wpftoolkit on how to use one.

Comment: Can you explain how to make it work in this situation? I am a rookie in WPF universe. The text box should wrap text to multiple line (the OOTB normal behavior) and it should have a non-editable text slug between the editable region. Exactly what @helb showed but must support multi-line and text wrapping. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the UI behave like a single TextBox, you probably need a customized TextBox control.

After experimenting with various events I came up with the following solution:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class MyTextBox : TextBox
    {
        public MyTextBox()
        {
            TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(MyTextBox_TextChanged);
            PreviewKeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(MyTextBox_PreviewKeyDown);
            PreviewTextInput += new TextCompositionEventHandler(MyTextBox_PreviewTextInput);
            DataObject.AddPastingHandler(this, new DataObjectPastingEventHandler(OnPaste));
        }

        private void OnPaste(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsValidPositionForEdit())
            {
                e.CancelCommand(); // do not allow pasting 
            }
        }

        void MyTextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsValidPositionForEdit())
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        void MyTextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsValidPositionForEdit())
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private bool IsValidPositionForEdit()
        {
            return SelectionStart <= this.before || SelectionStart >= this.before + ReadOnlyTextChunk.Length;
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ReadOnlyTextChunkProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ReadOnlyTextChunk", typeof(string), typeof(MyTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(""));
        public string ReadOnlyTextChunk
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ReadOnlyTextChunkProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ReadOnlyTextChunkProperty, value); }
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            Text = ReadOnlyTextChunk;
            this.before = 0;
            this.after = ReadOnlyTextChunk.Length;
        }

        void MyTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (TextChange ch in e.Changes)
            {
                if (ch.Offset <= this.before) // before text was modified
                {
                    this.before += ch.AddedLength - ch.RemovedLength;
                }
                else if (ch.Offset >= this.before + ReadOnlyTextChunk.Length) // after text was modified
                {
                    this.after += ch.AddedLength - ch.RemovedLength;
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Tab) // jump to after part
            {
                if (SelectionStart <= this.before)
                {
                    SelectionStart = this.before + ReadOnlyTextChunk.Length;
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    base.OnKeyDown(e);
                }
            }
        }

        private int before; // length of before part
        private int after; // length of after part
    }
}
```

Use it as follows:

```
<local:MyTextBox ReadOnlyTextChunk="Chunk2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="200" Height="50"/>
```

Result looks like this:

[image]